# Linux kernel system call naming convention

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Linux kernel uses SYSCALL_DEFINEn as name for syscall entry point. I understand that it is a macro and finally replaced by sys_sycallname() and 'n' is number of arguments they take. Is that convention used just for readability or any other specific purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into `include/linux/syscalls.h` of the Linux kernel source

Answer (score 0):

I think your thoughts are reasonable.

But I also think it's helpful to read the SYSCALL_DEFINEn codes further to understand the way that  parameters passing between the user space and kernel space, and how to trap to kernel space. Because these codes are CPU architecture dependent, although the basic ideas are common.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

In the past, syscalls are not defined in this way. The new way of defining syscalls, that is using SYSCALL_DEFINEx() macros, is for fixing a security issue.

For example the following commit is one of fixes:

```
commit 1a94bc34768e463a93cb3751819709ab0ea80a01
Author: Heiko Carstens <heiko.carstens@de.ibm.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 14 14:13:59 2009 +0100

    [CVE-2009-0029] System call wrapper infrastructure

    From: Martin Schwidefsky <schwidefsky@de.ibm.com>

    By selecting HAVE_SYSCALL_WRAPPERS architectures can activate
    system call wrappers in order to sign extend system call arguments.

    All architectures where the ABI defines that the caller of a function
    has to perform sign extension probably need this.
```

You can find more description of this problem in [the CVS page](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2009-0029):

> The ABI in the Linux kernel 2.6.28 and earlier on s390, powerpc,
>   sparc64, and mips 64-bit platforms requires that a 32-bit argument in
>   a 64-bit register was properly sign extended when sent from a
>   user-mode application, but cannot verify this, which allows local
>   users to cause a denial of service (crash) or possibly gain privileges
>   via a crafted system call.